# Where can I find Pauls' 1874 article on the n-queens problem?

Tags: history, chessboards, mathematics

Where can I find the following article, which concerns the [n-queens problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html)?

> E. Pauls, Das Maximalproblem der Damen auf dem Schachbrete, II, Deutsche Schachzeitung. Organ f¨ur das Gesammte Schachleben 29 (9)(1874) 257–267.

Comment: The purpose of Chess SE is to solve problems related to chess, not to be a private search engine. That is why I have downvoted your question. Best regards.

Comment: Sorry, this question concerns the famous problem of N Queens (in the case of Board 8 by 8: how to place 8 Queens without any attack on another)

Comment: OK, **after editing** your question I see how this question is related to Chess SE. I have retracted both my downvote and my vote to close this question. I have upvoted this post as well. Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick Pope's web site Chess Archaeology has a page titled "Chess Library"  where he lists a number of on-line chess periodicals.

http://www.chessarch.com/library/library.shtml

And, yes, the volume of DSz that you're asking for can be found there.

For German sources, the Deutsche Digital Bibliothek (https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/) can sometimes be useful:

https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb11184017_00259.html

Answer (score 8):

The only old documents I find available online from the *Deutsche Schachzeitung* periodical are from Volumes 20, 21, 44, 45, 56, 57, which are [available at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=deutsche%20schachzeitung). So if you really are after Pauls' exact article for historical reasons, you might have to track down a hard copy of Volume 29 at a library.

On the other hand, if you are primarily interested in the mathematical content of Pauls' article, then a decent (though also partial) exposition is available from ["A survey of known results and research areas for n-queens"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X07010394) by Jordan Bell and Brett Stevens, in *Discrete Mathematics* Volume 309, pp.1-31 (2009). For instance, they spell out Pauls' method of proof for the existence of solutions to the n-queens problem (which appears in the first part of the article for which you want the second part):

> **Theorem (Pauls 1874).** For all n>3, n non-attacking queens can be placed on the n x n standard chessboard.

The Bell--Stevens paper does point out that Pauls' part II gives a proof that the 92 solutions to the 8-queens problem given in 1850 by Nauck are exhaustive. But unfortunately, 
Pauls' method of proof isn't given. (That said, Pauls' work here is mentioned alongside Gauss' earlier claim that a brute force computation could be used to prove that 92 is the total number, so perhaps that gives a hint at how Pauls proceeds.)

**Edited to add:** Bell and Stevens do point to two other old secondary sources which they say offer "excellent summaries" of prior work done on the 8-queens problem. These are:

1. E. Lucas, *Récréations mathématiques*. 2ième éd., nouveau tirage. Librairie Scientifique et Technique Albert Blanchard, Paris, 1973.
2. T.B. Sprague, On the eight queens problem, *Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc.*, 17 (1899), pp. 43–68.

The first is [available online via Gallica](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3943s/f84.image) (see the section on "Le problème des huit reines"), but it appears not to discuss the work of Pauls; rather, it focuses on the work of Günther (S. Günther, Zur mathematischen Theorie des Schachbretts, *Arch. Math. Phys.*, 56 (3) (1874), pp. 281–292), which work also receives an English-language exposition in [an 1874 *Philosophical Magazine* article by Glaisher](http://books.google.com/books?id=nKxSCc5_cCcC&lpg=PA457&ots=3FsFz-lPDF&dq=glaisher%20on%20the%20problem%20of%20the%20eight%20queens&pg=PA457#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The Sprague piece is also available online, [via Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=jJvxAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA44&ots=ixwKA-Khby&dq=%22zur%20mathematischen%20theorie%20des%20schachbretts%22&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false), but sadly it doesn't address Pauls either; instead, it again offers a look more at the Günther/Glaisher work, but this does at least mean explicitly addressing the matter of the 92 8-queens solutions on the standard chessboard, among other things.

Answer (score 6):

For people stumbling on this question: volume 29 is available online though [Google Books](https://books.google.be/books/about/Deutsche_Schachzeitung.html?id=YORgAAAAcAAJ) since februari 2015.